# How to open an Inventory with an Item inside an Inventory

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

By just writing the code in one class and the write:

```
case "example":
     player.openInventory(exampleInv);
     break;
```

But because I like my things organized and well sorted I wrote the Inventory inside another class as the Inventory Click Event.

Here is the class with the `InvClickEvent`:

```
package de.t0x1ccr34t0r.charactertrails.listeners;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;

public class InventoryListener implements Listener{

    @EventHandler
    public void onInvClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
        if(event.getCurrentItem() == null) return;
        if(event.getView().getTitle() == "§5Trails:"){
            Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();
            event.setCancelled(true);
            if(event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().hasLocalizedName()) {
                switch (event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getLocalizedName()) {
                    case "Close":
                        player.closeInventory();
                        break;
                    case "Copper":
                        player.closeInventory();
                        break;
                    case "Iron":
                        player.closeInventory();
                        break;
                    case "Gold":
                        player.closeInventory();
                        break;
                    case "Diamond":
                        player.closeInventory();
                        break;
                    case "Emerald":
                        player.closeInventory();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it all says `player.closeinventory()` because the `player.openInventory()` doesn't work yet and with that I need help. I made several classes like the `copper_Inventory` which I show you here:

```
package de.t0x1ccr34t0r.charactertrails.inventories;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Copper_Inventory implements CommandExecutor {

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender1, Command cmd1, String s1, String[] strings1) {
        if(!(sender1 instanceof Player)) return false;
        Player player1 = (Player) sender1;

        Inventory copperInventory = Bukkit.createInventory(null , 4 * 9 , "§5Copper Trails:");

        ItemStack ia = new ItemStack(Material.BARRIER);
        ItemMeta ma = ia.getItemMeta();
        ma.setLocalizedName("Close");
        ma.setDisplayName("§cClose");
        ia.setItemMeta(ma);
        copperInventory.setItem(31 , ia);

        ItemStack ib = new ItemStack(Material.ARROW);
        ItemMeta mb = ib.getItemMeta();
        mb.setLocalizedName("Back");
        mb.setDisplayName("§7Back");
        ib.setItemMeta(mb);
        copperInventory.setItem(27 , ib);

        player1.openInventory(copperInventory);

        return false;
    }
}
```

So that code actually works. But only with an command in-game.
In the end, I want something like this:

```
case "copper":
     player.openInventory(copperInventory);
     break;
```

But this obviously doesn't work of course, because the program cant find "copperInventory".

I use the word copper in case "copper": from another class which looks like this and this already works:

```
package de.t0x1ccr34t0r.charactertrails.inventories;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main_Inventory implements CommandExecutor {
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        if(!(sender instanceof Player)) return false;
        Player player = (Player) sender;

        Inventory mainInventory = Bukkit.createInventory(null , 3 * 9 , "§5Trails:");

        ItemStack i1 = new ItemStack(Material.COPPER_INGOT);
        ItemMeta m1 = i1.getItemMeta();
        m1.setLocalizedName("Copper");
        m1.setDisplayName(ChatColor.WHITE + "example");
        i1.setItemMeta(m1);
        mainInventory.setItem(11 , i1);

        player.openInventory(mainInventory);

        return false;
    }
}
```

So my question is now: How do I do define the variable "copperInventory" from public class Copper_Inventory inside the "case "copper": in public class InventoryListener.

Also, I don't know if that is important, you may see these classes are not in the same package. I made multiple subpackages to keep everything smooth.

So in the end, my code should look like this:

```
case "copper":
     player.openInventory(copperInventory);
     break;
```

But I just don't know how to do this whilst having the variables inside other classes.

Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes because the variable is out of your actual scope. It have been create in another method, and now the variable by itself isn't accessible.

If you want to keep the same inventory (not specially recommended), you can put into an `HashMap<>()` and get it after. Exemple:

```
public class Copper_Inventory implements CommandExecutor {

    public static final HashMap<Player, Inventory> INVENTORIES = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        if(!(sender instanceof Player)) return false;
        Player player = (Player) sender;

        Inventory copperInventory = Bukkit.createInventory(null , 4 * 9 , "§5Copper 
Trails:");
        // fill inventory
        player.openInventory(copperInventory);
        INVENTORIES.put(player, copperInventory);
    }
}
```

Then, when closing inventory, use: `player.openInventort(Copper_Inventory.INVENTORIES.get(player))`.

But, the most recommended way is not this one.

#### You can simply re-open a new one

You can create a new class which can be like that:

```java
public class Inventories {

    public static Inventory createCopperInventory(Player p) {
        Inventory copperInventory = Bukkit.createInventory(null , 4 * 9 , "§5Copper 
Trails:");
        // fill inventory
        return copperInventory;
    }
}
```

And then, each time use `player.openInventory(Inventories.createCopperInventory(player))`.

Comment: Okay thanks dude. I am pretty new to programming and  i think I will use the second Method u gave me as an answer, if I understand this correctly. Thanks for helping

Comment: With pleasure bro. Good luck while learning Java and spigot API :) I suggest you to check [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76124681/10952503) about inventories, it can be useful for you x)

Comment: Sure man. I was first willing to ask you to add me on discord, because I can ask you questions that way, but I guess that would be really annoying for you because I have yet another question and I will have many more. But thanks :)

Comment: @ToxicFactoryGames I already have some people that come on discord for things like that, and I no longer want to do this. You can add how much question you want here, on SO. I'm always checking for tags [tag:spigot] and [tag:minecraft] and trying to answer to them so no worry

Comment: I understand that. The only problem with this webside is, that I run into problems and cluelessness very often and have an delay of three days here. But thanks for far dude

Comment: Why 3 days delay? You asked your question 17h ago, I answered 15 minutes after. You can check for the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76366017/timeline) for more

Comment: Yeah, I meant that I can only ask an question every three days. I dont know if its because of my current repuatation or smt but it says that

Comment: Did you got like closed & deleted posts? It could like you have been post-limited because of previous bad one. Thanks to this one, maybe you can post a new one

Comment: Yeah, I did have one bad one and I didnt even did anything worng. I showed all my code, but people startet saying I need to give more code. So  the score of that question was -2 and I deleted that afterwards. But I dont really know, I only asked 3 questions in total till now and none of them got any reputation without the negative one so yeah, maybe